# Doob's Optional Sample Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

the version of Doobs Optional sampling theorem that I Have is as follows:

Let $\sigma, \tau$ be bounded stopping times with $\sigma \leq \tau.$
Then we have

(i) If $(X_{t})$ is a martingale, then 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau} \mid F_{\sigma}] = X_{\sigma} \quad \text{and thus} \quad \mathbb{E}[X_{\tau}] = X_{0}
\end{align*}
(ii)If $(X_{t})$ is a sub-martingale (super-martingale), then 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau} \mid F_{\sigma}] \geq X_{\sigma} \quad (\mathbb{E}[X_{\tau} \mid F_{\sigma}] \leq X_{\sigma})
\end{align*}

My question is now: Why is it not if and only if? Because every konstant is a stopping time and therefore I could easily get the conditions for a martingale.

Comment: What if we have a process X such that $E[X_t| \mathscr{F}_s] = X_s$ but  $E|X_t| = + \infty$?

Comment: It is 'iff'. If the properties hold for all stopping times $\tau$ and $\sigma$ then the original process is a martingale/ super-martingale.